# How to reference/use the variables initialized by the constructor in other methods in a mfc application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

<strike>So, like the title said I can't seem to use the variables initialized in the constructor in the mfc application.</strike>

```
// CMFCApplication1View construction/destruction

CMFCApplication1View::CMFCApplication1View() noexcept
{
    // TODO: add construction code here
    int x1 = 0;
}
```

but when I use those variables in the `onDraw` method it gives the undefined error

```
void CMFCApplication1View::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
{   
    CMFCApplication1Doc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    pDC->Rectangle(20+x1, 30, 100+x1, 120);  //<- error here
}
```

Edit:
Ok so the way I asked the question was completely wrong, what I actually wanted to ask was how to declare member variables in an MFC application, (specifically the `CMFCApplication1View.cpp` file), that I can use in other member functions of the same class.

Comment: `int x1 = 0;` This defines a local variable `x1` inside the constructor. To make it available to other methods, define it as a member variable in the `CMFCApplication1View` class, instead.

Comment: Learn about variable scope.

Comment: HI, yeah sorry about that, while writing the question the first time I was thinking one thing and wrote completely something else. Sorry I changed the question now.

Comment: Learn about [class member variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members). Your class is `CMFCApplication1View` and you want to add a member variable to it. The fact that it is an MFC class has no relevance, it's still just a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a file like MFCApplication1View.h. Your class will be declared in that file or a similarly named file. Find the class declaration in the header file and modify like this:

```
class CMFCApplication1View
{
   // ... other stuff

   int x1;
};
```

You can even initialize it in the header file instead of the constructor (this is an alternate to the above, not an addition):

```
class CMFCApplication1View
{
   // ... other stuff

   int x1 = 0;
};
```